# Depth texture and fbo issues on opentk c# with intel hd 3000

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, fbo, depth-buffer

I'm currently facing a problem with intel hd graphics hardware to implement shadow mapping effects. I think that the code isn't far from what i want to have as results because this  code snippet works fine on ATI Mobility Radeon 5650 and Nvidia NVS 4200M, but doesn't work on Intel HD 3000 and 4000.

```
    GL.GenTextures(1, out ShadowMap);
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, ShadowMap);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest); 
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureCompareFunc, (int)All.Lequal);
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent32, SHADOW_MAP_SIZE, SHADOW_MAP_SIZE, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero);

    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);

    GL.GenFramebuffers(1, out FBO);
    GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FBO);

    DrawBuffersEnum dbe = DrawBuffersEnum.None;
    GL.DrawBuffers(0, ref dbe);

    GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, TextureTarget.Texture2D, ShadowMap, 0);


    FramebufferErrorCode status = GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer);

    GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
```

the "status" variable indicates FramebufferIncompletReadBuffer, so the use of this fbo won't be correct (rendering the scene from the light POV).
I've been seeing on web for this status and i didn't found an answer that solve my problem.
So What i'm doing wrong on this snippet and/or what can be the origin of this FBO issus.
Thanks in advance.
PS: In shaders I use 1.2 version and i'm supposed to sample ShadowMap texture as a depth map.

Answer (score 0):

For people who had encountered the sampe problem,
it's just updating the latest drivers, i thought about this before asking my question but Windows 7 indicated me that i had the latest drivers (it was false).